# Gridview binding not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to bind a GridView control with the following code. But I am getting error "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values." The error line is " p.MaterialName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("MaterialName"));" I have data in all fields in the Materials table. What is wrong with the code? Please help me to fix it.

```
public static List<Product> GetMaterials()
{
    SqlHelper objSqlHelper = new SqlHelper();
    SqlDataReader reader = objSqlHelper.ExecuteReader("GetMaterials");
    List<Product> objMaterials = new List<Product>();
    Product p = new Product();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        p.MaterialId = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("MaterialId"));
        p.MaterialName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("MaterialName"));
        p.desc = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("desc"));
        p.MaterialPrice = reader.GetDecimal(reader.GetOrdinal("MaterialPrice"));
        p.Datasheet = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Datasheet"));
        objMaterials.Add(p);
    }
    reader.Close();
    return objMaterials;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you said there should be data, but this is typically throw when data is missing.

Try checking if "MaterialName" is null in the database:

```
p.MaterialName = reader.IsDBNull("MaterialName")
                   ? null : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("MaterialName"))
```

If this works, but then you get the error on another line, you might have to check for nulls on those lines too.

---

For the "MaterialPrice" field, use something like this: *(if `p.MaterialPrice` is not nullable, replace `(decimal)null` with some default value like `0`)*

```
p.MaterialPrice
    = reader.IsDBNull("MaterialPrice")
        ? (decimal)null : reader.GetDecimal(reader.GetOrdinal("MaterialPrice"))
```

Comment: This works then I changed for the other but for MaterialPrice, I get compilation error "            p.MaterialPrice = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("MaterialPrice")) ? null : reader.GetDecimal(reader.GetOrdinal("MaterialPrice"));"

Comment: error Error 5 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'decimal'